# Excel VBA using XMLHTTP with Siteminder Secured site

Tags: excel, xmlhttprequest, siteminder, vba

I am completely new to using XMLHTTP and experimenting with trying to download a report off of our company's internet site using Excel VBA. The problem I seem to be running into is that the site is protected by Siteminder. I think I need to use an XMLHTTP.Open with GET but anyway I try all I just seem to get is the Siteminder HTML code. So I am trying to first use a post to send my username and password to Siteminder something like:

```
Function PostXmlData(vUrl As String, UserName As String, Password As String, xmlText     
As String
Dim XMLHttp As Object
Set XMLHttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
XMLHttp.Open "POST", vUrl, False, UserName, Password
XMLHttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml;charset=utf-8"   

XMLHttp.send (xmlText)
PostXmlData = XMLHttp.responseText
End Function

Sub Posttest ()
Dim add As String
Dim User As String
Dim Pass As String
Dim send As String
Dim ret As Variant

add = "https://mycompanywebsite.com/apps/application/Main/"
User = "username"
Pass = "password"
Send="DashboardId=http://mycompanywebsite.com/DAVCatalog/Dashboards/Teams/Client%20_
Extranet%20AM"

ret = PostXmlData(add, User, Pass, send)
End Sub
```

Am I on the right track or is this not even possible? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated or if there is some site someone could direct me to that would be helpful. THanks.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to load the `responseText` into an `XMLDocument` so that you can parse it. See example below (make sure you add the Microsoft XML reference to the reference library)

```
Dim xmldoc As MSXML2.DOMDocument

' Create a new XMLDocument to which to load the XML text
Set xmlDoc = New DOMDocument
xmldoc.LoadXML (xmlhttp.responseText)

' Fetch the XML
Set xmlhttp = CreateObject("Microsoft.xmlHTTP")
xmlhttp.Open "Get", yourURL, False
xmlhttp.send

' Create a new XMLDocument to which to load the XML text
Set xmlDoc = New DOMDocument
xmldoc.LoadXML (xmlhttp.responseText)
```

From here, you should be able to parse the XML using objects like `NodeList`, `DOMElement`, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I think I follow. But are you saying this will get me around the Siteminder protection. How would I send my logon/password to get authenticated? Sorry maybe I do just not understand.

Comment: Maybe others might be able to help (and/or correct me), but the page that you retrieve will have to XML (i.e. leading off with the XML tag, <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> or something of that nature). If it is, then the `responseText` can be loaded into and parsed by the DOMDocument like i have in the example above.

Comment: THanks Jaycal - I used your example but nothing seems to be loading. I tried both a GET per your code and also tried a PoST but either way, nother loads.

Comment: when you use a browser and log into your website, does the page that loads return HTML or XML? (just trying to figure out if the issue is with the text returned from the POST/GET or the page itself)

Comment: It is returning HTML. THanks!

Answer (score 0):

Could you post the SiteMinder HTML response?  Looks like authentication may be failing.   Try sending the credentials as a base64 encoded header instead of  supplying them to the XMLHttp componet.

This is the format.

Authorization: Basic QWxhZGRpbjpvcGVuIHNlc2FtZQ==

The string after 'Basic' is base64 encoded credentials in the 'id:password' format.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I apologize for the delay in responding back. I am trying to create an MSXML.XMLHTTPRequest Object but I just get an error message that "ActiveX Component can't create object". I also tried supplying the setrequestheader to the XMLHttp object but that fails too. Is there maybe a reference I need to add for this to work? Thanks again!